# Is it possible to show or hide certain Glimpse tabs on a per-request basis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I would like to extend Glimpse but extend it from different aspects.

So for example if I have two actions:

> /foo

and

> /bar

I would like to show different custom tabs for /foo and for /bar. Programmatic way would be preferable over web.config. I was looking for a solution to tell this from the tab implementation based on the actual context but found nothing.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to have a different set of tabs depending on the request.

The tab itself can decide to not collect and return information, but the tab will still appear, only not clickable as there is no data.

You could create one Tab that shows the details of all the different tabs you want to show conditionally and have that one decide what data to show or hide depending on the context.

This is something that we would like to support as well, but up until now did not had the time to work that in. Feel free to create an issue on [our issue tracker](http://www.github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues) if this is something you would like to do.

Comment: Thank you @cgijbels. I created the ticket. If you do not have time then is it something I can help with?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could make this work currently using a client-side extension that would stop certain tabs from rendering at certain times.

Not the most elegant approach to be sure, but it would work.

Comment: thanks but I don't like the idea to post-hide the tab. I would rather control it from the tab itself.